# MVC - Display messages from the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, toastr

Within my MVC application we have several situations where, depending on the business rules of the function, some messages should be displayed to the user.

We are currently using the Jquery "Toastr" library to display messages to the user. The development is as follows:

1) Configuring Message Settings (Alert Message.cshtml)

```html
@helper MostrarMensagensAlerta(Alerta alerta)
{
    if (alerta != null)
    {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            window.toastr.options.closeButton = '@alerta.MostrarBotaoFechar';
            window.toastr.options.newestOnTop = '@alerta.MostrarNoTopo';

            @foreach (Aperam.Biblioteca.Util.Base.Entidades.MensagemAlerta mensagem in alerta.MensagensAlerta)
            {
                string tipoAlerta = mensagem.TipoAlerta.ToString("F").ToLower();                
                @: var opcoes = { /* Adicione atributos específidos dos alertas Toastr aqui */ };

                @:opcoes.closeButton = true;
                @:opcoes.progressBar = true;
                @:opcoes.positionClass = "toast-top-right";

                if (mensagem.ManterAlerta)
                {
                    @:opcoes.timeOut = 0;
                    @:opcoes.extendedTimeout = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    @:opcoes.timeOut = 10000;
                    @:opcoes.extendedTimeOut = 10000;
                }

                var texto = mensagem.Mensagem.Replace("\r\n", "<br /> ").Replace("\r", "<br /> ").Replace("\n", "<br /> ").Replace("'", "");
                @:window.toastr['@tipoAlerta']('@(new HtmlString(texto))', '@mensagem.Titulo', opcoes);
            }
        });
    </script>
    }
}
```

2) Partial view added to the main page (_Message.cshtml):

```html
@if (TempData.ContainsKey("Alerta"))
{
  Alerta alerta = TempData["Alerta"] as Alerta;
  @MensagemAlerta.MostrarMensagensAlerta(alerta);
}
```

3) Into the master page, I added the div related to partial view of messages:

```html
<div id="div-mensagens">
  @Html.Partial("_Mensagem")
</div>
```

4) Inside the controller, I have a method that adds messages by TempData:

```html
public MensagemAlerta AdicionarMensagemAlerta(string mensagem, TipoAlerta tipoAlerta = TipoAlerta.Info)
{
 string titulo = string.Empty;

 switch (tipoAlerta)
 {
  case TipoAlerta.Error:
   titulo = "Erro";
   break;
  case TipoAlerta.Info:
  case TipoAlerta.Success:
   titulo = "Informação";
   break;
  case TipoAlerta.Warning:
   titulo = "Alerta";
   break;
 }

 Alerta alerta = TempData["Alerta"] as Alerta;
 alerta = alerta ?? new Alerta();

 var mensagemAlerta = alerta.AdicionarMensagemAlerta(titulo, mensagem, tipoAlerta);
 TempData["Alerta"] = alerta;
 return mensagemAlerta;

}
```

Message viewing happens correctly when the request is by POST and the main page (_Layout.cshtml) is loaded again.
The problem is when calls are made via ajax and only the partial view is loaded or no item is returned. In these conditions, if the partial view "_Message.cshtml" is not reloaded, messages are not displayed.

Another problem is that my standard error handling also uses this function to display the messages. This way, when an error occurs from an ajax call, the message is only displayed when the user reloads the entire page.

A palliative solution that I am using is, at the end of every ajax call, to make a new call to the server forcing the reloading of the message div, as follows:

```html
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, options) {
        if(options.url.toString().split('/')[2] != 'Mensagens')
            exibirMensagens();
    });

 function exibirMensagens() {
        $("#div-mensagens").load('@Url.Action("Mensagens")');
 }



public ActionResult Mensagens()
{
    return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_Mensagem.cshtml");
}
```

I'm not very satisfied with the solution that was given, as I'm forcing a new call to the server unnecessarily.

I would like to share this problem with you to find the best way to handle this situation.

Comment: Nobody going to go through all that, cut it down a bit to the core problem

Comment: This is the perfect scenario to use `SignalR`

Comment: @Hackerman, do you have a example that how i can use SignalR in this scenario? I don't know about this library...

Comment: https://balajiramesh.wordpress.com/2016/06/03/real-time-server-side-push-notifications-using-microsoft-signalr/

Comment: @Hackerman, in this example the messagem will be shown to all users that are using the page in that moment? In my scenario, the message depends of the user action.

Comment: You can modify the code to do that...